# Diagnose Postgres intermittent connection/query error

Tags: postgresql

We have a postgresql working as a master with a few WAH replicas.

The database is being written on by one process, but the process has been slow lately. It works super fast, then halts for some time and then continues again.

I connect to this postgres instance using Dbeaver. It shows random halting on queries/connection/refresh. This behavior was not shown earlier. It is also not observed on the replicas.

The database is running in a docker inside a VM. There seems to be no resource contention. Also, postgresql exporter sends statistics to Prometheus and those seem fine as well.

I used `ping -s 50000` to diagnose any connections to the host, it's stable.
Also wrote a test application in c# to do sample queries on the databases, these are stable as well.

The writer process is not written by our team and it's not easy (but possible) to add more logs.

The DBMS creates no erroneous logs.

What are possible ways to diagnose such intermittent connection problems?

Comment: "The database is running in a docker inside a VM". Start by running the DB natively, so that you can eliminate two possible origins of trouble.

Comment: "It works super fast, then halts for some time and then continues again."  What does this mean?  What tools are you using to diagnose this, and what do you see within those tools?

Comment: @jjanes This is from the writer application that writes data to the master node. It is quite fast for some time, then halts for some time and these random periods of fast/halt continue.